# Is there a way to see the current memory utilization of ASP.NET session state?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-state

Is there a way to see the current memory utilization of ASP.NET session state?

I have an application that uses a third-party WebControl and the App Pool keeps restarting. I'm thinking that it's due to memory pressure, and I want to check to see how much is being stored in session state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a tool for this [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) that you could use to profile your session.

Answer (score 1):

The [Glimpse Session Tab](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/wiki/Session-Tab) will show you what is in session, but not the actual size.